# Generate a PDF of an admin page

Tags: 7, files, users

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to generate a PDF of an admin page in Drupal. I've looked at a bunch of custom modules but they seem only to work on nodes, which I know are not used to generate admin items. I have a client I've given limited back-end access to that would like a "Create a PDF" button placed in one of the admin areas. Does anyone have any recommendations? Here are my specs:

Drupal version: 7.24
Modules tried: mpdf, print

Thanks! -Dave

Comment: why you want print admin pages?

Comment: Hi zhilevan, I don't need to print admin pages, I need to PDF a single admin page containing specific data. It is something the client requested.

Comment: _"containing specific data"_ - **What** is that _specific data_? A list of users? A list of nodes? Blocks? A specific configuration page? Which one? Your question, as well as your answer are very vague.

Comment: If all you need is a specific page, just take a screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

Dear friend I suggest you if you only want provide a visual manual for your customer install pdf printer ( software that print result is pdf like foxit,nitro etc) then in each page ctrl+P (print ) and enjoy ( admin pages are not very much and not need put yourself in complex ways,It seems you want fast and short way to achive it ) :)

Comment: Hi Zhilevan, I like your suggestion. I think Google Chrome even comes standard with a print to pdf option and I know Firefox has an extension for it. Thanks for taking the time to respond and help me out! -Dave

Comment: @healthcommdave your welcome, sometimes I should extend his view and not limit him/herself to a restrict solution :). it is my pleasure can help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the data your talking about is accessible to views you might try: https://drupal.org/project/views_pdf. You can easily restrict access to the view, as well as provide it with a /admin path prefix.

As with previous comments, you might need to be a bit more specific.

Comment: Hi user792406, as of now the page is not a view nor is it accessible to views. Is there a fairly painless way to make it accessible to views? I have looked at views_pdf and it works great for front-end stuff but haven't tried it with /admin yet. Thank you for your help! -Dave